# Can I set an LLDB breakpoint when multiple Rust source files share the same name?

Tags: rust, lldb

**Background:** In Rust, you typically have multiple source files called `mod.rs`. For example:

```
app_name
  src
    main.rs
    foo
      mod.rs
    bar
      mod.rs
```

**Problem:** I can't find a way to distinguish one `mod.rs` from another when setting an LLDB breakpoint:

```
$ cargo build
$ rust-lldb target/debug/app_name

(lldb) breakpoint set -f mod.rs -l 10
Breakpoint 1: 2 locations.

(lldb) breakpoint set -f foo/mod.rs -l 10
Breakpoint 2: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.

(lldb) breakpoint set -f src/foo/mod.rs -l 10
Breakpoint 3: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

This issue arises most commonly with `mod.rs`. More generally, it arises anytime multiple source files share the same name.

**Question**: Is there a way to set a breakpoint at line 10 of `foo/mod.rs` but not at line 10 of `bar/mod.rs`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28713043/155423 (although it doesn't seem to help here).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the *absolute path* to the file. In my case, I compiled in the `/tmp` directory on OS X, which is actually `/private/tmp`. That means that I can do something like this:

```
breakpoint set --file /private/tmp/debug/src/bar/mod.rs --line 2
```

I figured this out by looking at the DWARF debugging information:

```
dwarfdump target/debug/debug.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/debug | grep mod.rs
```

There are also a few workarounds if this doesn't work:

1. Break at a function instead: `breakpoint set --name my_func`. It's unlikely that you will have the same method name, but here you can use the module name as well: `breakpoint set --name foo::my_func`.
2. Disable non-interesting duplicate breakpoints. `breakpoint set` establishes a *logical* breakpoint with a numeric ID (like `1`), and then real breakpoints that match the condition have a sub ID (like `1.1`). You can see these with `breakpoint list` and then disable others with `breakpoint disable 1.1`.

Comment: Will breaking at a function name work given name mangling (on by default)?

Comment: @SamElliott yes. Debuggers (should) know about name mangling and de-mangle by default. If they don't, `lldb` allows you to set a breakpoint with a regex: `breakpoint set -r '.*foo.*'`